# How to convert this from curl to php

Tags: php, curl

Does someone know how to convert this from to php? Or maybe can convert.

```
curl -X DELETE "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/fjsdf834u8fhsdfh343/purge_cache" \
    -H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
    -H "X-Auth-Key: c254fsdfg34320b638f5e225c545fsddasc5cfdda41" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{"purge_everything":true}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init ('https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/fjsdf834u8fhsdfh343/purge_cache');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
curl_setopt ($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
    'X-Auth-Email: user@example.com',
    'X-Auth-Key: c254fsdfg34320b638f5e225c545fsddasc5cfdda41',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"purge_everything":true}');

echo curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: @jason check your credentials

Comment: everithing is ok with credentials

Comment: wait I have a message ""Sorry, you do not have access to purge cache for that zone id or that zone id is invalid"